# How to create custom Django widget to use abbr element?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm still pretty new to `Django` framework and I would like my forms' pages to use the following HTML for each checkboxes instead of the default one used by `CheckboxSelectMultiple`:

```
<abbr title="formation.abbr">formation.label</abbr>
```

- `formation.abbr` is the `CharField` property from my `Formation`'s instance ;
- `formation.label` is the `TextField` property from my `Formation`'s instance ;

### `forms.py`

```
class InternalActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'formations'
        )
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
            'formations': CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

### Current solution

I modified the `__unicode__` method to output both `self.abbr` and `self.description` which is okish. However I would prefer a fine control on my output so I can use the correct semantic.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s (%s)' % (self.abbr, self.description)
```

How should I proceed ? Should I tweak my `forms.py` or `views.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how your form is described as you've not included it, but if you're wanting to add a separate tag that is not described in your form, then I would suggest using cycle also:

```
{% for field in form %}
 <abbr title="{% cycle 'abbr1' 'abbr2' 'abbr3' %}">{{ field.label_tag }}</abbr>
 ...
```

Comment: your answer is not relevant to my initial or updated question. Please modify it